# How to use lapply or a family of the apply function for calling a function within a function in R?

Tags: r, apply, lapply, mapply, tapply

How to use lapply or a family of the apply function for calling a function within a function?
I have a parent function (i.e., `hrat`) that calls a sister function (i.e., `drat`) within it. I would like to apply this function over certain vector. I am providing a code to demonstrate my logic. I get following error message.

Code:

```
 drat <- function(y){
   x <- y * 5
   return(x)
 }

 hrat <- function(z, j, drat){
  y <- z +1
  w <- drat(y) + j
  return(w)
  }

 z <- c(1:5)
 j <- 4
 result <- lapply(z,j, function(x) hrat(x, drat(x)))
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
 Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
 object 'j' of mode 'function' was not found
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You just have the arguments reversed. `lapply(z, hrat, drat)` works. The second argument is the function you want to call, and extra arguments are passed to that function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid confusion, it is better to have anonymous function call

```
lapply(z, function(x) hrat(x, drat))
```

Comment: I am sorry, I just needed to add extra object that is now giving problem. After adding object j, it does not like it.